# g++/gcc cannot find header file named String.hpp

Tags: c++, string, gcc, g++

I created my own string class and named it 'String.hpp' and included this file in my 'String.cpp'. However, g++/gcc says it could not find 'String.hpp' no matter what I tried. Furthermore, it also cannot find the class named 'String'.

I thought strings in c++ were lowercase 'string'. Is 'String' a reserved class or word in C++?

EDIT:

I seemed to have solved this issue by redoing the code body. The names have all remained the same. I guess the next time this happens, I will look through my own code and try to find a problem there.

Comment: Show the important parts of the actual code; we cannot help with this level of information.

Comment: What OS? Windows doesn't care about capitalisation in files. 'String' is not a reserved word and shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Please show more of the *actual* files content. As you write it, there's no trouble. But the devil is in the details ...

Comment: What is the syntax of your `#include` statement?

Comment: How do you invoke the compiler, include all parameters?

Comment: I invoke the compiler with 'g++ String.cpp'. I realized if I removed the contents from my 2 files and include only the barebones class declaration, then it compiles. I suppose this must mean something is wrong with my actual code.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ a string is a standard defined type not a keyword. And is use like so

```
#include <string>

//elsewhere 

std::string str("hi");
```

If your compiler can't find your string header then it ins't going to know about your class whatever happens.

You should include your own header like this. Note the quotations, not the angle braces. Angle braces mean that the compiler should search the include directories not the current directory.

```
#include "String.hpp"
//else where
yournamepsace::String str //etc...
```

This won't collide with the standard version, you should however make sure that it is namespaced as you will be no doubt dealing with very similar names.

If the compiler still can't see then you need to make sure that the file is in the same directory that your source file is in.

Finally if this is some sort of programming practice then carry on but if this is production code please consider using the std::string, the world doesn't need another string. :)

Comment: Hi 111111, I do namespace it.

Comment: @chlong Is it still not working? what is your include line and what is your directory structure we need this information to give you a better answer.

Comment: Hi 111111, I just redid the entire code and it is not complaining about the #include anymore. The names are still the same. As for directory structure, the 2 files 'String.cpp' and 'String.hpp' are in the same directory.

Comment: @chlong Try this from the source directory, `g++ -c String.cpp` what happens? Please attach the actual the actual compiler output.

Answer (score 2):

My suspicion is you are doing a

```
#include <String.hpp>
```

This excludes the current directory from the where the compiler will search for the file.  If that is the case, you want to do

```
#include "String.hpp"
```

in which case, the compiler will also search the current directory.

Comment: Hi John, I thought of that too. The 2 files are in the same directory and I do indeed use '#include "String.hpp"